# sorting of array using tasm assembler

Tags: arrays, assembly, sorting, tasm

How can we sort a `array` in assembly language by taking the input dynamically using tasm
 assembler?

```
.model data
.small
array db 90h,10h,23h,33h
.
.
.code


int 3
end
```

Comment: When you post your current code it's typically expected that it actually does something (preferably very close to what it's _intended_ to do). As it stands you're asking people to fill in the blanks, with the "blanks" being the entire program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some sort algorithm - for example [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Although, for very small arrays (as in your example) you better use more simple algorithm as [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

The later, because of the very easy implementation (smaller code) will be faster than the complex Quicksort for small arrays.